# Is there an alternative to VS 2012?

Tags: programming

Hey I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask and sorry if its not, But I'm needing an alternative to Visual Studio 2012 for Linux and I found 2 so far called Netbean and Eclipse, Out of those or any other ones you guys may know of which is the closest or similar to VS 2012? Thank you for your time guys.

Comment: This question was asked a while back on Stack Overflow, and the answers have a lot of great information on the different ways you can develop C/C++ on Linux. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do c# development I would recommend using [Mono Develop](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/monodevelop/)

Answer (score 0):

It depends. In what language you are going to program.

If it is java, eclipse or netbeans are excelent.

C++ or C You can use netbeans, codeblocks, or try qt creator

If you are planning to program c#. Use Mono.